# Can't navigate to home page after facebook login with Ionic framework

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, facebook-authentication

I've tried putting `this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);` in different places within the code but after I successfully login to my app with facebook then it won't navigate to the homepage.

I'm using Ionic Framework with Firebase.  The userprofile data is stored to the backend but neither .push nor .setRoot is pushing the homepage.

```
 facebookLogin() {
    this.facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(result=>{
      const credentials=firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.authResponse.accessToken);
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials).then((success)=>{
            this.userProfile = success;
            this.firebaseLogin.setUpUser(credentials, success);
      })
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    }).catch(err=>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(err))
    })
  }
```

Comment: Are you using `tabs`?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using tabs.  It's the ionic tab app.

Comment: I actually got this working.  My problem now is a delay.  It redirects the user to the homepage after login but it's a slight delay...the login page flashes a second before redirecting to the HomePage.

Comment: Hope you can use `loader control` no?